# Google maps geocoding API address correction hierarchy

Tags: api, geocode

I'm trying to understand in what order and what precedence the geocoding API takes when processing the pieces of the address that was passed to it.

I have this example of why I'm asking the question.  The correct address is:

```
2608 N Ocean Bv
Myrtle Beach, SC 29577
```

Running that into the API, absolutely no problems:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2608+n+ocean+bv+myrtle+beach+sc+29577&sensor=false

However, take this typoed version of the address:

```
2608 N Ocean Bv
Mrytle Beach, NC 29577
```

The city is spelled wrong, and it has the wrong state.  Street number, name and zip code are correct.  Mrytle Beach does not exist anywhere, and not in NC.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2608+n+ocean+bv+mrytle+beach+nc+29577&sensor=false

Google comes back with:

```
2608 N Ocean Bv
North Myrtle Beach, SC  29582
```

Now, that is a valid address.  But why did Google decide that was the address I was looking for?

If you remove the incorrect state, and don't replace it with anything:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2608+n+ocean+bv+mrytle+beach+29577&sensor=false
```

Google returns a corrected version of the correct address.  So it seems that state trumps zip code - however, North Myrtle Beach does not exist in NC.

I'm thinking that omitting city and state eliminates most of this issue - but I'd like to understand why - if possible.  Thanks.

Edit:

After some further playing around - it seems that Google looks for a city match as highest priority, then state - ignore all else.  In this case:

1. Can't find a city called "Mrytle Beach" anywhere in the world.
2. Let's start in NC then and find the closest match to the street address if there is one.
3. Ah, here is the closest one to NC - in North Myrtle Beach.

If you change the state in my example above from NC to FL, the more southern Myrtle Beach match is closer to Florida than the more northern North Myrtle Beach address, and that is what Google returns.

I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind this.  It seems that this sort of logic would be near last resort - or at least after making use of the zip code passed - which it appears it doesn't use at all.